# How organize a client database SQL

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I would like an advice about my database. I have a lot of informations and I don't know if it's better to use only one table or to batch informations.

For exemple I have this informations: Firstname, Lastname, Nationality Country, Citizenship country, Resident country, Previous job, current job, and a lot of more information.

should I create one table ? or a table for Personal information (Id, lastname, firstname), a table for countries (Nationality, Resident, ...) , a table for job (Previous, current, ...)

Thanks.

Comment: Dealing with personal info get ready to have a lot of tables. A lot of temporal tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is always about what purpose is your db going to serve. If you are writing a simple app maybe one table would do the job. If you are looking into creating an organized data mart where you will store info about multiple entities and relationships the second approach is the best.

Read about data mart schemas, especially the star schema